# Can I say, "I wash my teeth"?

Tags: word-usage

I was checking tests from my students. One of them talking about daily routine wrote, "**I wash my teeth**". Can I say it instead of **"I *brush* my teeth"** or is it completely wrong?

Comment: It's not usual but is pretty understandable. Brushing is one way of washing after all. It could mean that they gargled some mouth-wash, but that would normally be said as 'I gargle some mouth-wash'. So a bit ambiguous, but definitely indicates the type of activity engaged,

Comment: @simonatrcl: If the "cleaning" process involved just mouthwash or other liquid with no brushing, you'd probably refer to ***washing** [out]* or ***rinsing*** your ***mouth***, not your ***teeth***.

Comment: Yep. I was just giving some alternatives. I did say it was unusual.

Comment: No one says wash teeth in English unless, for example, you are a botanist working with animals skeletons or a paleontologist working with skulls and whatnot. The point is that for one's own teeth, it is completely unidiomatic.

Comment: @Lambie - I agree, although I suppose one might (humorously?) use _wash my teeth_ if they were referring to their own dentures.

Comment: @J.R. Actually, dentures are usually soaked. :)

Comment: I'm not sure about it being non idiomatic, it might depend where you're from. CS Lewis (Ireland/England) always called it washing his teeth. And below there's a comment about the same in Wales. I'll ask my friends from India what they say.

Answer (score 9):

Grammatically, **I wash my teeth** is quite correct. Idiomatically, it is not. People don't talk like that.

As you note, the usual expression is **to brush one's teeth** because one usually uses a toothbrush to clean them.

People sometimes use twigs and plants to clean their teeth when the usual equipment is lacking. But even then, **wash** isn't an easy fit.

I recall as a child once having my mouth washed out with soap - after using bad language - but I'm not sure that my teeth benefited from the washing.

Comment: I knew a Welsh girl around 1970 who said 'wash my teeth'; she said her whole family did and the people she knew in Cardiff as a kid.

Comment: Likewise, Mid Wales in 1980s. Although brwsio'r danedd exists in Welsh, golchi'r danedd might have been the local idiom.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes. I felt sure, when reading some of the comments about it being completely non-idiomatic, that I had heard it somewhere - perhaps it was in Wales, as I used to go there a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In Ireland, one will often hear people saying that they washed their teeth. So it seems to me that “I washed my teeth” is just fine, both grammatically and idiomatically.

Comment: Did you maybe post this answer twice?

Comment: Aha! We;ve had Wales, now Ireland - obviously it's Celtic.

Answer (score 0):

My family have always said "wash" and we are English. I do not think it is that unusual.

Comment: Every regional dialect is different... From the USA, I could only agree with the answer Ronald gave: "People don't talk like that."  :-)

Comment: Gene Hofstadt says it in 'Mad Men', although he does have dementia!

Answer (score 0):

When I was a small child (about 5 or so) we had family friends stay over on occasion. While my sister and I were brought up to use the phraseology "I'm going to clean my teeth", our friend (about our age) would say "I'm going to wash my teeth." It's just how they worded it in their family, and I learned (among other things) that private vocabularies of different families were often inexplicably and irrationally different.

Hence, although I have never heard the phrase since, I understand that "to wash one's teeth" is as correct as "to clean one's teeth".

Comment: Were they Welsh by any chance? See above comments. I grew up in Norfolk, where we too, would talk of *cleaning our teeth*, not *brushing*. I suspect *cleaning* is widespread in England.

Comment: @WS2 - 'cleaning your teeth' is what I was brought up to say in  south London.

Comment: @ws2 My grandmother was from Norfolk and while she had many sayings and customs that nobody else around here said, 'washing teeth' was not one of them. This might make an amusing aside to an answer, to note that a very tiny minority of people in a particular region *might* say it, but to say it is idiomatic is massively misleading the OP.

Comment: @WS2 Possibly. I lived in Gloucestershire at the time. They lived within a couple of hours drive. I was far too young to have a grasp of geography.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, it isn't idiomatic. Native English speakers, in the main, would not say it. The fact that a few people have suggested it might be a regional variation does not deter me in this stance. In nearly 50 years I have never once heard it said by anyone in person, or on television (where various dialects are represented). If you are a non-native speaker of English and you said this you would be corrected by the vast majority of people who would think you had made a mistake through being a non-native speaker.

The greatest majority of people use the verb *to brush*:

> I'm going to brush my teeth.

There are various other methods of achieving oral hygiene besides brushing, and collectively we do say '*clean*':

> *I'm going to clean my teeth*.

'Cleaning' one's teeth might include brushing, flossing etc, but also some people seem to say 'cleaning' in preference to 'brushing'.

Notably though, even when using the product known as 'mouthwash', we do not say 'washing' our teeth. Most people would say '*rinsing*':

> After I've brushed, I rinse my teeth with mouthwash.

If you're still in doubt, check [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brush%20your%20teeth%2Cwash%20your%20teeth%2Cclean%20your%20teeth%2C%20brushing%20my%20teeth%2C%20washing%20my%20teeth%2C%20cleaning%20my%20teeth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrush%20your%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwash%20your%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclean%20your%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbrushing%20my%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwashing%20my%20teeth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccleaning%20my%20teeth%3B%2Cc0). Google ngrams by themselves do not always prove something is right or wrong, but they take a sample from literature available on Google Books which gives some indication of trends. As you will see, 'brush' and 'brushing' are most widely used. There are some uses of 'clean' and 'cleaning'. 'Wash' and 'washing' practically flatline.

Comment: Have you read the various answers and comments where people clearly have used or heard the expression "washing one's teeth"? Do you not believe them or are you just choosing to ignore them?

Comment: @WS2 I know they are wrong. They are mainly about kids saying it. Kids say things wrong, and then they learn the right way. Any adults that say it are getting funny looks behind their backs. If the OP is a non-native speaker and they say it, they will be corrected by a native speaker sooner or later, I can guarantee that.